# How to validate an abstract method's arguments for all implementations?

Tags: java, validation, abstract-class

I am writing an abstract json parser with an abstract method

```java
    T parse(JsonNode node);
```

My goal is to validate the argument (node). It should be not null and if it is in fact the instance of NullNode.class should be returned.

Didn't find much on the web.

```java
public abstract class AbstractJsonParser<T> extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<T> {
....
abstract T parse(JsonNode node);

@Override
    protected T readInternal(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        JsonNode parentNode = objectMapper.readTree(inputMessage.getBody());
        return parse(parentNode);
    }
}
```

Is there any way in java8 to do this? I'll have many concrete implementations and I don't want to check every time for null values.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can address the null checking code duplication by simply checking for null on `parentNode` in `readInternal`, then deciding whether to return `parse` or an instance of `NullNode`. Another thing and possibly a problem is that you're returning `T`. How is `NullNode` going to fit any arbitrary type?

Answer (score 0):

You could make `parse` a concrete method and implement the part

> It should be not null and if it is, in fact, the instance of `NullNode.class` should be returned.

there. Any implementation would be able to refer to it by `super.parse(node)`.

If you have to force subclasses to implement their part of parsing, [the template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) may come in handy. You define common parts in `AbstractJsonParser#parse` and delegate abstract steps to subclasses.